# Jquery Mobile, submit form on event OnChange

Tags: jquery, mobile

with this code I send a form on event onChange of a  menu:

```
$(function() {
$('#tag_id').change(function() {
    $.mobile.changePage('page.php', {
        type: 'get',
        data: $('form#formAnnunci').serialize()
    });
});
```

});

It works fine... but when it open "page.php", with correct data sended, I can't resend the form. On Change the form, the page remains fixed.. without sending data. Why?
Thanks!